# Смещение всего сайта при - filter: blur()

Tags: html, css

Всем привет, нужна помощь, такая у меня проблема:
У меня есть страница, и я сделал блок информации который появляется при нажатии на кнопку, так вот, когда этот блок появляется, все на фоне размывается, всё кроме шапки и подвала, они находятся в другом файле и у них `position: fixed`. Всё бы ничего, но при срабатывании функции, всё кроме шапки и подвала смещается вниз, а смещается из-за того, что на фоне стоит изображение, а убирать его я не собираюсь, как можно это исправить?

Код и изображения:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
var informationButton = document.querySelector('.testInformation');
document.querySelector('.wrapper').style.transition = 'filter .5s';
// document.querySelector('.informationBlock').style.transition = 'transform .5s;';

informationButton.onclick = function () {
 if (checkBlur == 0) {
  document.querySelector('.informationBlock').style.display = 'block';
  document.querySelector('.wrapper').style.filter = 'blur(5px)';
  document.querySelector('.informationBlock').style.filter = 'blur(0px) !important';
  setTimeout(function() {
   document.querySelector('.informationBlock').style.transform = 'scale(1)';
   document.querySelector('.informationBlock').style.position = 'fixed';
  }, 300);
  checkBlur++;
 } else {
  document.querySelector('.informationBlock').style.transform = 'scale(0.001)';
  setTimeout(function() {
   document.querySelector('.wrapper').style.filter = 'blur(0px)'; 
   document.querySelector('.informationBlock').style.display = 'none';
   document.querySelector('.informationBlock').style.position = 'absolute';
  }, 300);
  checkBlur--;
 }
}
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Didact Gothic', sans-serif;
    outline: none;
}

/* Навигационная панель */

.header img {
 background-size: cover;
 width: 100%;
}

/* Контент */

.promoImage {
 width: 60vh;
 height: 60vh;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
 position: absolute;
 top: 15%;
 left: 5%;
 z-index: 0;
 font-size: 29px;
 text-align: center;
 border-radius: 8px;
 box-shadow: 3px 4px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.6);
}

.points {
 position: absolute;
 top: 15%;
 left: calc(5% + 60vh + 5%);
 font-size: 29px;
}

.points li {
 margin-bottom: 3vh;
 list-style-type: circle;
}

span {
 font-size: 35px;
}

/* Форма регистрации */

body {
 background: rgb(9%, 12%, 95%, .4);
}

.accountForm {
 position: relative;
 margin-bottom: 27vh;
 z-index: 1;
 padding-left: 5%;
}

.accountForm form {
 position: relative;
 margin-top: 3%;
}

.accountForm input, .accountForm button {
 display: block;
}

.accountForm input {
 width: 24.5%;
 height: 5vh;
 font-size: 21px;
 border-radius: 8px;
 padding-left: .5%; 
 border: none;
 margin-bottom: .7%;
 box-shadow: 1px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

.accountForm button, .editPassword button {
 width: 17%;
 height: 6vh;
 font-size: 21px;
 border-radius: 15px;
}

.authBlock p {
 font-size: 22px;
}

.authBlock a {
 color: white;
 text-decoration: none;
}

.authBlock a:hover {
 color: red;
}

.accountImage {
 width: 60vh;
 height: 60vh;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 0;
 font-size: 29px;
 text-align: center;
 border-radius: 8px; 
 top: 0;
 left: 60%;
 box-shadow: 3px 4px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.6);
}

.informationBlock {
 width: 70%;
 height: 70vh;
 background: white;
 position: absolute;
 top: 15vh;
 left: 15%;
 border-radius: 8px;
 box-shadow: 3px 4px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.6);
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 30px;
 transform: scale(0.001);
 /*transform: scale(1);*/
 display: none;
 transition: transform .4s;
}

.informationBlock ul {
 text-align: left;
 margin-left: 4vh;
 margin-top: 5vh;
 line-height: 4.5vh;
 font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<?php

include 'configurations/topAndBottom.php';
include 'configurations/language.php';

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

 <style type="text/css">
  #hellopreloader_preload{
   display: block;
   position: fixed;
   z-index: 99999;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   min-width: 1000px;
   background: #a2a5fa url(http://hello-site.ru//main/images/preloads/spinning-circles.svg) center center no-repeat;
   background-size:41px;
  }
 </style>
 <div id="hellopreloader">
  <div id="hellopreloader_preload"></div>
 </div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var hellopreloader = document.getElementById("hellopreloader_preload");
  document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
  function fadeOutnojquery(el){
   el.style.opacity = 1;
   var interhellopreloader = setInterval(function() {
    el.style.opacity = el.style.opacity - 0.05;
    document.body.style.overflow = 'visible';
    if (el.style.opacity <= 0.05) { 
     clearInterval(interhellopreloader);
     hellopreloader.style.display = "none";
    }
   },16);
  }
  window.onload = function() {
   setTimeout(function(){
    fadeOutnojquery(hellopreloader);
   },1000);
  };
 </script>

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Didact+Gothic" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title><?php echo $title ?></title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">
<!-- topLine -->
   <img class="img" src="images/background.jpg">
<!-- bottomLine -->
  </div>
  <div class="content">
   <div class="promoImage">
    Здесь будет фото
   </div>
   <ul class="points">
    <li><?php echo $liOne ?></li>
    <li><?php echo $liTwo ?></li>
    <li><?php echo $liThree ?></li>
    <span><?php echo $span ?></span>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="accountForm">
   <form>
    <span id="createAccount"><?php echo $create ?></span><br><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="<?php echo $fio ?>">
    <input type="text" placeholder="<?php echo $class ?>">
    <input type="text" placeholder="<?php echo $post ?>">
    <input type="text" placeholder="<?php echo $password ?>">
    <input type="text" placeholder="<?php echo $confPassword ?>">
    <button><?php echo $registration ?></button>
   </form>
   <div class="accountImage">
    Здесь будет фото
   </div>
   <div class="authBlock">
    <br><br><br><p id="regForm"><?php echo $authBlock ?></p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="informationBlock">
  Информация:
  <ul>
   <li>Для того чтобы начать тестирование, нажмите на кнопку сообщений наверху и нажмите - Перейти</li>
   <li>Чтобы продолжить, нажмите - Начать.</li>
   <li>Впишите идентификатор учитиля, для того, чтобы ваш учитель потом получил уведомление.</li>
   <li>После этого нажмите - Далее и вас перенаправят на страницу с тестированием.</li>
   <li>На тест вам даётя 40 минут.</li>
   <li>В тесте могут попадатся вопросы как с обычным выбором, так и с функцией перестраивания и вписывания правильного ответа.</li>
   <li>В тесте могут попадатся от 1 и больше правильных ответов.</li>
   <li>Если нужно вписать правильный ответ, он будет указывать только на определённый термин, вы не сможете<br>описать что-либо своими словами.</li>
   <li>Если в тесте были найдены ошибки, просим вас срочно обратится к учителю, чтобы он исправил ошибку.</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
 <script src="scripts/main.js"></script>
 <script src="scripts/smoothScroll.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

И ещё повторюсь, у меня шапка и подвал отдельно находятся, по этому при запуске кнопок не будет, но на скринах есть кнопка - Информация, она и запускает функцию.

Comment: Предоставьте код и по возможности скриншоты

Comment: для начала код приложить в снипете, скрин как щас, скрин как вы хотите

Comment: Всё, я всё добавил

Comment: а я добавил стили только блока с информацией, нужно ли добавлять остальное? и на счёт проблемы, на первом скрине видно большое расстояние, оно появляется после нажатия, а нужно чтобы было как на втором скрине - до нажатия

Comment: Так вы используете scale. Изменяете масштаб, поэтому всё и отдаляется

Comment: Нет, это не из-за этого, пробовал убрать, всё равно так же

Comment: Нууууу, так как можно это решить?

Comment: ссылку кинь на сайт

Comment: https://seventyeight.myportfolio.kz/onlinetest/index.php вот

Comment: Нажмите на кнопку "Информация", и посмотрите на блок где написано "Здесь будет фото" и блок списка, они сдвигаются вниз

Comment: А, кажется я нашел проблему из-за чего всё это, потому что у меня стоит :
top: 15%; 
Теперь я сделал:
top: 15vh;
И всё нормально теперь, спасибо за помощь